# upgrade openssl for old version xampp

Tags: openssl, xampp

I am trying to enable TLS 1.1 on my xampp apache server, but it seems like the version of OpenSSL is too old for that. (Error: SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.1')

Can anyone help me how I can upgrade OpenSSL? or something easier approach? I need to keep PHP version as 5.3.1.

My configuration is Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please clarify what operating system you are using, and what distribution of that OS if applicable.

Comment: I'm not sure if that matters. As I mentioned it is xampp. (if it really matters, it is sitting Windows 7.)

Comment: Ahhh, sorry.  My ignorance is flaring.  Just download a newer xampp package.  https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: The newest xampp package does not have php 5.3.1 version that I need to keep.

Comment: You definitely need OpenSSL 1.0.1 or higher, and (acccording to the changelog) httpd+mod_ssl 2.2.23 or higher (including 2.4.anything). Good luck. You might be better off just putting a separate TLS terminator (like nginx, haproxy, or a second/newer httpd) in front of your server.